# Books recommendation to understand Quantum Confined Stark Effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, resource-recommendations, semiconductor-physics, photonics

I am starting a PhD on a photonic component involved with QCSE. The problem is that I have a Master degree in electronical engineering, not in fundamental physics, and I need to understand the QCSE in GaAs QW for my PhD.

What are the basic books you would recommend me to get it? (preferrably a total of less than 1000 pages, or less than 2000)

You can consider I understand the basics of electromagnetism and thermodynamics, and a nice glimpse at semiconductor physics. However, I am not familiar with hamiltonians or high-level optics.

Preferrably books available on link.springer.com

Comment: I strongly recommend you ask your supervisor for books and read the phd theses and papers he/she already already supervised or published.

Comment: Thank you, he already gave me a few books on the component itself, but I'm kind of looking for a bonus book on something more fundamental and general because sometimes these books considers I have knowledge on fundamental physics and I don't really.

Comment: Quantum wells, wires and dots by Paul Harrison was always a favourite when I started, it does have a computational emphasis. A little book, Quantum Wells by Shik Alexandra was worth reading too.